# Starting command using “/“ instead of “\”

Tags: equations, catcodes, renewcommand

This seems like a very random question, but I just got the Apple Magic Keyboard for iPad Air 5th generation. The key “\” is half of the size of that of “/“. The “\” key is placed also in the edge and it is hard to press accurately.

So I’ve been thinking if I could start a command like `/int_0^1/alpha(t)dt`, or maybe `@int_0^1 @alpha(t)dt` instead of `\int_0^1\alpha(t)dt`.

I haven’t decided on what symbol to use instead, so “@“ is just one possibility I might use. What is a general way I can start a command using a customized key?

Comment: `\catcode\`\/=0  `  you can use any letter (see `xii.tex` for a command using `j`) of course many things may break if they are not expecting a standard escape character but...

Comment: Why don't you remap the keys so the key you want to use produces the code for `\ `? I'd think that would be a whole lot easier than dealing with the complications? Just because it is marked `/` doesn't mean it has to be mapped to `/`.

Comment: Ask the Japanese first for the trouble they had with the backslash and the  ¥ (yen sign)! As @DavidCarlisle wrote it can easily be done, but you looking for trouble!

Comment: @cfr I really haven’t heard or found anything for key mapping for iPad Air with keyboard. I know it is possible for macbook though.

Comment: I suppose the question is whether Apple will let you do it on a system they've locked down. But that's the kind of fix you likely want here. Another possibility is to type the character you want and then just replace it before compiling. This could be a scripted part of your build recipe if that's the kind of thing you use. Or you could trigger the replacement when saving the file or whatever. Any of that will likely be a whole lot less trouble than switching the escape character.

Comment: @cfr I am using Overleaf right now and catcode the escape key as David Carlisle said cause one problem: there is no auto-complete anymore...

Comment: @WilliamSun well yes almost no system for auto-complete or syntax highlighting will understand if you change the basic syntax characters for tex. Even if it is easy to do in tex.